# PHP Shell Excution of ffmpeg Not Reading Bash Profile

Tags: php, ffmpeg, environment-variables

I understand that is a odd question and may be very specific, but I recently installed `ffmpeg` on a shared hosting service. While I can execute all tasks from an SSH console, when making the exact same call in PHP, I get this error.

> error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

It did the same thing in PuTTY, until I updated the `~/.bash_profile` with this line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/searay330/ffmpeg/lib
```

Does PHP not use `~/.bash_profile`, or is there a different file that needs to be updated? Any information on this topic is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: im betting on a permission issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it in `.bashrc` instead. `.bash_profile` is only read when an interactive login-shell is used, but `.bashrc` is read when Bash starts interactively but is not a login-shell. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for more info. So, you can't really use `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. You need to set the environment variable in PHP prior to calling `shell_exec()`.

```
<?php
putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/searay330/ffmpeg/lib');
shell_exec('...');
```

Comment: That worked like a charm i appreciate the effort as well as the external information.